# Printing the table

Tags: assembly, mips, mars-simulator

I want to print the table of any given integer in mars mips

printing the table of any given integer in mars mips

```
.data
msg: .asciiz"Enter the table "
msg2: .asciiz"The table is\n"
.text
li $t1,1

li $v0,4
la $a0,msg
syscall
li $v0,5
syscall
move $t0,$v0

li $v0,4
la $a0,msg2
syscall

ble $t1,10,table

table:
mul $t2,$t0,$t1
addi $t0,$t0,1

li $v0,1
move $a0,$t2
syscall

ble $t1,10,table
```

I expext the table of integer to be printed but at run time program got crashed

Comment: MARS also gave you a message, including the address where the crash occured (i.e. which line of code). You should include the information in your question.

Comment: actually this question was also posted by me, but now somehow I manage to get the answer , and  I am also sharing the correct code as well                                   .data
msg: .asciiz"Enter the table "
msg2: .asciiz"The table is\n"
space: .asciiz" "
.text
li $t1,1
li $t2,11

li $v0,4
la $a0,msg
syscall
li $v0,5
syscall
move $t0,$v0
li $v0,4
la $a0,msg2
syscall

bne $t1,$t2,table
table:
mul $t5,$t0,$t1
addi $t1,$t1,1

move $a0,$t5
li $v0,1
syscall
li $v0,4
la $a0,space
syscall

bne $t1,$t2,table